# recording ADTS AAC Audio using AudioRecord and MediaCodec on Android but no sound when playback

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, aac, adts

i am trying to record audio in ADTS AAC but when recording all things going good (file is correctly create with good format an data are showing fill inside) but no sound are playing when try to open with player like VLC . can anyone please help me solve this issues ?

```
enter code here private void getDataFromEncoder(byte[] data, int size){

    ByteBuffer[] codecInputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[] codecOutputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();
    long pts = System.nanoTime() / 1000 - mPresentTimeUs;

    int inBufferIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer( -1 ); // kTimeoutUs ou -1
    if (inBufferIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = codecInputBuffers[inBufferIndex];
        buffer.clear();
       // size = buffer.limit();
        byte[] zeroes = new byte[size];
        buffer.put(zeroes);
        // buffer.put(data, 0, size);
        codec.queueInputBuffer(inBufferIndex, 0 , size,  pts , 0);

    }

    for (; ; ) {
        int outBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(audioInfo, 0 ); // kTimeoutUs
        // outBufferIndex vaut -2

        if (outBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) { //si le format a changer
            onAudioFormat(codec.getOutputFormat()); // on recupere la valeur du nouveau format mediaformat
              /*mediaformat = codec.getOutputFormat();*/

        } else if (outBufferIndex >= 0) {
            //This ByteBuffer is AAC
            int outBitsSize = audioInfo.size; //
            int outPacketSize = outBitsSize + 7;    // 7 is ADTS size
            ByteBuffer outBuf = codecOutputBuffers[outBufferIndex];

            outBuf.position(audioInfo.offset);
            outBuf.limit(audioInfo.offset + outBitsSize);
            try {
               // data = new byte[outPacketSize];  //space for ADTS header included
                addADTStoPacket(data, outPacketSize);
                outBuf.get(data, 7, outBitsSize);
                outBuf.position(audioInfo.offset);
                mFileStream.write(data, 0, outPacketSize);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed writing bitstream data to file");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            outBuf.clear();
            codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outBufferIndex, false);

        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

}

my add ADTS headers method

```
enter code here     private void addADTStoPacket(byte[] packet, int packetLen) {
    int profile = 2;  //AAC LC
    //39=MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectELD;
    int freqIdx = 4;  //44.1KHz
    int chanCfg = 2;  //CPE

    // fill in ADTS data
    packet[0] = (byte)0xFF; // conversion hexadecimal a decimal - il y a seize unités de 0 à F, on parle donc d'hexadécimal.
    packet[1] = (byte)0xF9; // installe la version ADTS dans MPEG-2 (0xF1) au lieu de MPEG-4 (0xF9)
    packet[2] = (byte)(((profile-1)<<6) + (freqIdx<<2) +(chanCfg>>2));
    packet[3] = (byte)(((chanCfg&3)<<6) + (packetLen>>11));
    packet[4] = (byte)((packetLen&0x7FF) >> 3);
    packet[5] = (byte)(((packetLen&7)<<5) + 0x1F);
    packet[6] = (byte)0xFC; // 0xFC est également correct si vous ne connaissez pas la valeur de la plénitude du tampon
}
```

Comment: You are putting a blank buffer (zeroes) to the codec input queue, it must be your byte array called 'data' instead no?

Comment: @E.Abdel thanks for your answers i try it and it record well but when playing with player the sound is weird don't know what i do wrong in my code who make sound play as if scratching on the metal with a nail. please i need ur helps . thanks

Comment: i finally solved the problem by adjust parameter of audioRecord = new AudioRecord( /*parameters*/) with parameter of ADTS header . i.e samplerate = 44.1KHz number of channel 2 , profile AAC LC . thanks  @E.Abdel hundred millions times for support .